# How to call a python file using python script

Tags: python

I have python file .py and I wanted to run through python script.

Comment: What's in the file? Simply `import`ing it will run the code in the file, although if it's a script with `if __name__ == '__main__':` you may want to use the `subprocess` module to actually run it as a separate script.

Comment: to Execute .py file not importing

Comment: That's exactly what importing a .py file does.

Comment: @Strigoides: no, importing is different from executing a script.

Comment: @BryanOakley in some ways yes (`__name__` for example), but when you import a .py file it is executed. There are some contexts it wouldn't work in though, I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'your_script.py'])
```